# Code slows down the compiler, how to fix?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

So i've used [this website](https://thatthinginswift.com/debug-long-compile-times-swift/) to find what causes my compiler to compile for almost 2 minutes. How could I optimize this code part to work properly and not slow down the compiler?

```
100801.11ms /ViewControllers/FastGame/FastGameVC.swift:160:10   instance method configureCollectionView()\
```

This is my code:

```
func configureCollectionView()
{
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    if (screenSize.size.width > 320)
    {
        if (self.currentLogo!.originalRandomLetters!.count > 14)
        {
            layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 8, bottom: 20, right: 8)
            self.constaintHeightViewRandomLetter.constant = 26 + (self.collectionLetters.frame.width/8 - 3) * 2 + 20
        }
        else
        {
            layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 8 + (self.view.frame.width/8 - 3) / 2, bottom: 20, right: 8 + (self.view.frame.width/8 - 3) / 2)
            self.constaintHeightViewRandomLetter.constant = 26 + (self.collectionLetters.frame.width/8 - 3) * 2 + 20
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (self.currentLogo!.originalRandomLetters!.count > 14)
        {
            layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 8, bottom: 10, right: 8)
            self.constaintHeightViewRandomLetter.constant = 10 + (self.collectionLetters.frame.width/8 - 3) * 2
        }
        else
        {
            layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 8 + (self.view.frame.width/8 - 3) / 2, bottom: 10, right: 8 + (self.view.frame.width/8 - 3) / 2)
            self.constaintHeightViewRandomLetter.constant = 10 + (self.collectionLetters.frame.width/8 - 3) * 2
        }
    }

    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width/8 - 3, height: self.view.frame.width/8 - 3)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 4
    self.collectionLetters!.collectionViewLayout = layout
    //self.constaintHeightViewRandomLetter.constant = 26 + (self.collectionLetters.frame.width/8 - 3) * 2 + 20
    self.viewContainerRandomLetters.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.viewAnswerLetters.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing lines one by one and seeing if that changes anything? For example, does removing the if statement condition (just set it to `true` to test) speed it up at all?

Comment: Yeah, I've found what caused it. It's the if/else calculation of the locations. But I don't have a clue how to fix them or replace them to something better.

Comment: Maybe post the code for `.originalRandomLetters` instead of what you're showing now (if that's causing the problem)?

Comment: Am I reading this correct? Slow *build* times? Have you tried some "quasi" hardcoding? Maybe set up an internal variable for `self.currentLogo!.originalRandomLetters!.count`? Possibly something that removes the forced-unwrapping?

Comment: I would certainly start by extracting the commonly used values to local variables ie `self.CurrentLogo.originalRandomLetters.count` `self.view.frame` and `self.collectionLetters.frame`